# python code coverage using coverage.py report analysis

Tags: python, coverage.py

Folllowing is my coverage statistics:

Coverage: 76%
310 statements   253 run 94 branches 57 missing 13 excluded 27 partial

Can anyone please help with the formula to calculate this %?

Comment: Yes Branches 94

Comment: The answer is only approximate. Tell me more about why you want to calculate the number, maybe there's another way I can help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the exact total from those displayed numbers, because of how branches are counted.  But roughly, the total is:

```
total = (executions)/(possible executions)
```

The number of executions is the number of statements plus the number of branches, minus the number of excluded statements.

```
possible executions = statements + branches - excluded
```

The number of executions is the number of run statements plus the number of taken branches. We don't display the number of taken branches, so you have to estimate:

```
executions = (run statements) + (total branches - partial branches)
```

That gives us:

```
total = (253+94-27)/(310+94-13) = 81.8%
```